# BeanInstantiationException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Понимаю в чем проблема, но не понимаю из-за чего и где капать.

Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/evaluation/evaluationdata/{stId}"})
public String evaluationData(@PathVariable("stId") int stId,
                             @ModelAttribute("semester") int semester, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("listAcademicSubject", academicSubjectService.getListAcademicSubject());
    model.addAttribute("listEvaluation", evaluationService.listEvaluationByGroupIdAndStudentId(stId));
    model.addAttribute("listSchedule", scheduleService.getListSheduleByGroupAndBySemester(studentService.getStudentById(stId).getGroupStudent(), 1));

return "evaluationdata";
}
```

Сервис:

```
@Override
public List<Evaluation> listEvaluationByGroupIdAndStudentId(int studentId) {
    return evaluationDao.listEvaluationByGroupIdAndStudentId(studentId);
}
```

DAO:

```
@Query("select ev from Evaluation ev where ev.studentId =:stId order by ev.date")
public List<Evaluation> listEvaluationByGroupIdAndStudentId(@Param("stId") int studentId);
```

Не понимаю, где не хватает дефолтного конструктора.

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [int]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: int.()
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:107)

Comment: Покажите код формы.

Comment: Теперь понял в чем заключалась проблема. Не было никакой формы.
В чем собственно заключалась проблема? В том, что данных не поступало из формы?

Comment: Аннотацией `@ModelAttribute` обычно метят [DTO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO), принимающий данные из формы.